# Php assign session array in while

Tags: php, arrays, database, session, while-loop

I would give the datas in the databases and assign to session as array in PHP. I assign value session in while loop. I was think the session is an array but i looked and i view is not an array. I would want to do create session in the while i give the datas of the databases and give the datas of the databases as array in this session. After use this session with foreach in another page.

Code :

```
<?php

$vericek15 = $baglanti10 -> prepare("select * from sepet where kulad = :kulad");
$vericek15 -> bindParam(':kulad', $kulad8);
$vericek15 -> execute();
$vericek16 = $baglanti10 -> prepare("select * from sepet where kulad = ?");
$vericek16 -> bindParam(1, $kulad8);
$vericek16 -> execute();
$vericek16say = $vericek16 -> rowCount();

if ($vericek16say == 0) {
?>
    <div id="surunyokl">
        <label>Your cart is empty</label>
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
    #surunyokl{
        position: absolute;
        top: 325px;
        left: 625px;
    }
    </style>

<?php
} else {
?>
<div id="sepettablo">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Image of product</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Product</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Piece</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Price</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Delete</th>
        </tr>

<?php
while($bilgiler15 = $vericek15 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $vericek17 = $baglanti10 -> prepare("select * from urunlist where urunad = :urunad");
    $vericek17 -> bindParam(':urunad', $bilgiler15['urunad']);
    $vericek17 -> execute();

    $vericek18 = $baglanti10 -> prepare("select * from urunlistresim where urunad = :urunad2");
    $vericek18 -> bindParam(':urunad2', $bilgiler15['urunad']);
    $vericek18 -> execute();

    $bilgi18 = $vericek18 -> fetch();

    while($bilgiler17 = $vericek17 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $_SESSION['b'] = $bilgiler15['urunad'];
        $_SESSION['urunadi'] = $bilgiler15['urunad'];
        $_SESSION['urunadet'] = $bilgiler15['urunadet'];
        $_SESSION['urunfiyat'] = $bilgiler17['urunfiyat'];

        if ($bilgiler17['urunadet'] == 0) {

        }

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><img src="'.$bilgi18['resimyol'].'" height="100" width="100"></td>';
        echo '<td style="width:500px;text-align:center;">'.$bilgiler15['urunad'].'</td>';

        if ($bilgiler17['urunadet'] == 0) {

          echo '<td style="width:125px;text-align:center;"><input type="button" value="-" onclick="azalt('.$bilgiler15['no'].');">'.$bilgiler15['urunadet'].'</td>';

        }else {

          echo '<td style="width:125px;text-align:center;"><input type="button" value="-" onclick="azalt('.$bilgiler15['no'].');">'.$bilgiler15['urunadet'].'<input type="button" value="+" onclick="artir('.$bilgiler15['no'].');"></td>';

        }
        echo '<td style="width:75px;text-align:center;">'.$bilgiler17['urunfiyat'].'<label><b> € </b></label></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="sil('.$bilgiler15['no'].')"></td>';

        echo '</tr>';

        @$fiyat += $bilgiler17['urunfiyat'] * $bilgiler15['urunadet'];
        @$toplamadet += $bilgiler15['urunadet'];
        if ($toplamadet == 1) {
            $kargo = 5;
        }elseif ($toplamadet > 1) {
            $kargo = 5 + ($toplamadet - 1);
        }else{
        }
        $toplam = $fiyat + $kargo;
    }

}
```

I tried but i not couldn't.

How can i do this?

Please share code model.

I need your help.

Note : My code is complicated. Pardon me. I hoe you understand.

Comment: Show us the code you are using please

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok.

Comment: The PHP $_SESSION variable is an array, unless you have done something to damage it on your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I have no idea what the code is doing but you are basically not setting arrays into the SESSIOn you are overwriting data each time round the while loop

```
    $_SESSION['b'] = $bilgiler15['urunad'];
    $_SESSION['urunadi'] = $bilgiler15['urunad'];
    $_SESSION['urunadet'] = $bilgiler15['urunadet'];
    $_SESSION['urunfiyat'] = $bilgiler17['urunfiyat'];
```

Amend it so you are adding a new item to the session each time round the while loop

```
    $_SESSION['b'][] = $bilgiler15['urunad'];
    $_SESSION['urunadi'][] = $bilgiler15['urunad'];
    $_SESSION['urunadet'][] = $bilgiler15['urunadet'];
    $_SESSION['urunfiyat'][] = $bilgiler17['urunfiyat'];
```

Now you will have many `$_SESSION['b']` occurances etc

It woudl probably be easier to do this so each row is added as a new occurance in the array like this

```
$_SESSION['bilgiler15'][] = array(
                                'b'         => $bilgiler15['urunad'],
                                'urunadi'   => $bilgiler15['urunad'],
                                'urunadet'  => $bilgiler15['urunadet'],
                                'urunfiyat' => $bilgiler17['urunfiyat'],
                                );
```

Or maybe

```
$_SESSION['bilgiler15'][$bilgiler15['urunad']] = 
                        array(
                                'urunadi'   => $bilgiler15['urunad'],
                                'urunadet'  => $bilgiler15['urunadet'],
                                'urunfiyat' => $bilgiler17['urunfiyat'],
                            );
```

Comment: I can don't use **  []  ** in session

Comment: How? Help please

Comment: every time the while loop run the value of the session change. I can't create a array.